# Why does logging output show in console host, but not in ISE? (v4.0)

Tags: c++, powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm referencing a DLL file containing a C++ class that I need for an API.  The default constructor for that class pipes a wall of text to a stream I can't touch, as far as I can tell. I redirected output streams one at a time to try and isolate it, and reached 6 without successfully affecting the text.  It's logging data, and I don't care about it in this context; I'd like it to go away.

The text is not returned by the constructor (the object is returned successfully as normal), it's just sent to console during the constructor's execution.  I think that's why Out-Null and > $null do nothing.

The text is *not* evident in the console when I run the same procedure in the ISE!  It's a telling clue, and I went looking for environment differences -- but there are a ton of environment differences.  Which ones should I investigate?

Answer (score 1):

I think the important difference is that PowerShell.exe is a console subsystem application.  Any sort of output to stdout (printf, cout << 'foo', etc) is going to show up in the console.  ISE on the other hand, is a Windows subsystem application - no console.  What you see as a console pane in ISE, is merely another tool window that looks and behaves like a console just like the NuGet Package Manager console in Visual Studio.